# Understanding websockets in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, websocket

As far as I know an appropiate buffer size for websocket's .ReceiveAsync method is 8192 bytes. If i provide a buffer size bigger than 8192 it works aswell. Does .net framework handle the resizing of the buffer, or is it good practice to handle it myself?

I came up with following code to handle frame sizes bigger than 8192 bytes:

```
var payload = new byte[FRAME_SIZE];
    var receivedFrame = await websocket.ReceiveAsync(payload, CancellationToken.None);

    while (!receivedFrame.EndOfMessage)
    {
        var frame = new byte[FRAME_SIZE]; // which is 8192
        receivedFrame = await websocket.ReceiveAsync(frame, CancellationToken.None);

        var nextBuffer = new byte[payload.Length + receivedFrame.Count];

        Array.Copy(payload, 0, nextBuffer, 0, payload.Length);
        Array.Copy(frame, 0, nextBuffer, payload.Length, receivedFrame.Count);

        payload = nextBuffer;
    }
```

The code works just fine but it's slow when receiving data bigger than 100 mb. Setting the buffer size to 100mb or more is much faster.

Comment: Don't allocate a new array for each frame. Create `frame` once and re-use it. You could do the same for `payload` if you create it with a very, very generous size. That should be ok, if it's only created once during the life time of your app. You code keeps copying the same data over and over again, which could be avoided, or at least minimized by resizing in a smarter way.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Makes sense! It's faster now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider something like this to reduce the number of allocations and copies:

```cs
var buffer = new byte[FRAME_SIZE];
var received = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer.AsMemory(), default);
var totalBytes = received.Count;

while (!received.EndOfMessage) {
    if (buffer.Length < totalBytes + FRAME_SIZE) {
        Array.Resize(ref buffer, buffer.Length * 2);
    }
    
    received = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer.AsMemory(totalBytes..), default);
    totalBytes += received.Count;
}

var result = buffer.AsMemory(..totalBytes);
```

The code is untested though.

The general idea is to start with a small buffer that *doubles* in size each time a new frame needs to be read. So the more frames we receive, the less often we have to resize. `Array.Resize()` will take care of allocating and copying the required memory.

Additionally we only use a single buffer that we keep writing into, but for each `ReceiveAsync()` call we start writing at the buffer offset where the previous call stopped.

In the end we return a `Memory<byte>` view over the parts of the payload buffer that have actually been written to. Depending on your code you might want to use `Span<byte>`/`AsSpan()` instead.

Comment: Yep, it definetely is smater that way. I can then use ReadOnlySpan over the buffer to pass it to the jsonserializer. it works' faster now (: